# Permutations drawn from different intersecting sets

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I'm looking to create non-repeating permutations of length $N$ drawn from $N$ finite and possibly intersecting sets. Specifically, element $i$ is always drawn from set $S_i$.  A simple example, if:

$S_1 = \{1,2,3\} \\
S_2 = \{3,4\} \\
S_3 = \{5\}$

then all valid permutations are $[1,3,5]$, $[2,3,5]$, $[1,4,5]$, $[2,4,5]$, and $[3,4,5]$. Note that $[3,3,5]$ not valid because of the repeated value.

I'm interested in 1) calculating the total number of valid permutations and 2) an algorithm to efficiently calculate the *next* permutation given the current one - similar to the common [pivot/swap/reverse strategy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-permutation/) for standard permutations where all elements are drawn from the same set.

Apologies if a permutation isn't the right way to think about this problem.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It looks more like a programming issue than a math problem...I'd start with the "easier" problem:  given the $S_i$, determine whether or not there is a single valid selection.

Comment: It's an algorithm problem, so I was initially unsure whether to post it here or in a programming forum. My thinking was that this is the right place because I want to gain insight into the problem, not code it. Your suggestion is a good one. I believe one criteria for any valid selection to exist is that $\lvert \cup S_i \rvert \geq N$, but this is not sufficient.

Comment: @bmit At least one valid selection exists if and only if the Hall condition is satisfied. The Hall condition is that, for any subset $K\subseteq N$, that $|\bigcup_{i\in K}S_i|\ge |K|$. That is, any $k$ sets chosen from $S_1,\dots,S_n$ have a union whose size is at least $k$.  This is [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no efficient answer to problem $1$. If you could count the number of solutions efficiently, then you would be able to compute the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)) of any $n\times n$ ${01}$-matrix efficiently, but the permanent problem is $\#\mathrm P$ complete.

Indeed, given an $n\times n$ matrix whose entries are all either zero or one, you let $S_i$ be the set of column indices $j$ such that there exists a $1$ at row $i$ and column $j$, for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Then the number of ways to choose distinct elements from each $S_i$ is exactly the permanent of that matrix.

For problem $2$, the fastest way to march through all of the solutions is probably Knuth's [dancing links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links) algorithm, also called DLX. The setup for this problem is a zero-one matrix, together with a subset $C$ of the columns. The problem is to choose a subset $R$ of the rows, such that

- For two rows $r_1,r_2$ in $R$, there is no column where both $r_1$ and $r_2$ have a $1$.
- For any column $c\in C$, there is some $r\in R$ which has a $1$ in column $c$.

The columns in $C$ are the "strict" columns, which must be covered exactly once, while the other columns are "slack," and may be either uncovered or covered once. This is a slight generalization of the set cover problem; in the set cover problem, all columns are strict.

Knuth's dancing link's algorithm efficiently generates all solutions to this problem. Here is how your selection problem is encoded in a way to be solved by dancing links. Let us say that $|S_1\cup \dots \cup S_n|=r$.

- The binary matrix has $n+r$ columns. For each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, there is a strict column labeled $i$, and for each $x\in S_1\cup \dots \cup S_n$, there is a slack column labeled $x$.
- There are $|S_1|+\dots+|S_n|$ rows. For each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, and for each $x\in S_i$, there is a row labeled "Pick $x$ from $S_i$". This row has a $1$ in the column labeled $i$, and a $1$ in the column labeled $x$, and all other spots are zero.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Is it reasonable to say that the best answer to 1) is to essentially count the solutions generated by DLX? Or is calculating the permanent directly a more efficient solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know. To my knowledge, the fastest way to count is to march through them all.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding because it seems like the 0-1 matrix that you calculate the permanent of wouldn't be square. Wouldn't the matrix have $n$ rows and $r$ columns?

Comment: Call your problem the SDR problem. I am not claiming that every SDR problem can be solved with a permanent. I am claiming the reverse, that every permanent can be realized as an SDR problem. (SDR stands for "system of distinct representatives"). You are correct, you cannot use permanents to solve every SDR problem, because the matrix would not be square (well, maybe there is a clever workaround, I am not sure).